# jQuery blur on inputs of the same name, not indivdual radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of radio buttons that I'd like the user to be able to tab to, then use the arrow keys to select.

Once they have chosen the radio button, I'd like them to tab to the next set and the previous set will hide.

```
$("input").blur(function(){ $(this).closest('div').slideUp(); });
```

So, if you click the radio button in the first section, then click the radio button in the second section, the first section hides. This is great.

The issue I have is that any time anyone uses the arrow keys to select the next input in the same section, it hides the whole section.

http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/qdzXLw

How can I create a blur function that will only fire when you leave a group of radio buttons, not any individual input?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if tab key is press or not try this

```
        <div>
            <h4>Question 1</h4>
            <p><label for=""><input type="radio" name="question-1" value="1" />Answer 1</label></p>
            <p><label for=""><input type="radio" name="question-1" value="2" />Answer 2</label></p>
            <p><label for=""><input type="radio" name="question-1" value="3" />Answer 3</label></p>
            <p><label for=""><input type="radio" name="question-1" value="4" />Answer 4</label></p>
            <p><label for=""><input type="radio" name="question-1" value="5" />Answer 5</label></p>
            <p><label for=""><input type="radio" name="question-1" value="6" />Answer 6</label></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4>Question 1</h4>
            <p><label for=""><input type="radio" name="question-2" value="1" />Answer 1</label></p>
            <p><label for=""><input type="radio" name="question-2" value="2" />Answer 2</label></p>
            <p><label for=""><input type="radio" name="question-2" value="3" />Answer 3</label></p>
            <p><label for=""><input type="radio" name="question-2" value="4" />Answer 4</label></p>
            <p><label for=""><input type="radio" name="question-2" value="5" />Answer 5</label></p>
            <p><label for=""><input type="radio" name="question-2" value="6" />Answer 6</label></p>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).keydown(function (event) {
                switch (event.keyCode) {
                    case 9:
                        $("input[type='radio']").blur(function () {
                            $(this).closest('div').slideUp();
                        });
                        break;
                }
            });

            $("input[type='radio']").blur(function () {
                $('body').append('Focus lost');
            });
        </script>
```

Hope this will help you.